# checking for bad NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata

i am new to Objective-C and going through the book, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide to Objective-C programming..

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/imagess/logos/ps_logo2.png"];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        NSError *error =nil;

        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                             returningResponse:NULL
                                                         error:&error];



        if(!data){
            NSLog(@"fetch failed %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return 1;
        }

        NSLog(@"the files is %lu bytes", [data length]);

        BOOL written = [data writeToFile:@"/tmp/google.png"
                                 options:NSDataWritingAtomic
                                   error:&error];

        if(!written){
            NSLog(@"write failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
            return 1;
        }
        NSLog(@"Success!");

        NSData *readData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/google.png"];
        NSLog(@"the file read from disk has %lu bytes", [readData length]);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

the problem is this, if i change the *url to http://aFakeDomain.com/imimimi/myImage.png then my data object will be nill because there is no HOST and everything works fine.. but if i use google as the domain and point to a bad file location then the data object stil has header info and is NOT nil thus i never get the error i should.

whats the best way to make sure that the *url successfully found a file.

thanks

Comment: check the response, it will have a status code that should tell you the result of the request

Comment: You have to distinguish between "couldn't connect" and "connected but didn't get the requested resource". The first is a connection error; the second isn't. As the two answers you've gotten so far indicate, you need to look at the response to know whether the server was able to give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to pass a response to the `NSURLConnection` call and then check its status code:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&httpResponse
                                                     error:&error];
int code = [httpResponse statusCode];
```

you will get a `404` status code in your case.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSUrlResponce *responce = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                         returningResponse:&responce
                                                     error:&error];

if (error) {
    // handle the error
}

if (![[responce MIMEType] isEqualToString:@"image/png"]) {
    // failed to get png file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also some mistakes of the file name;
instead of @"/tmp/google.png", you should use the code list blow:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"google.png"];
```